# How would I get this to work with user input?

Tags: c++

I don't have much experience working with matrices. How would I get my matrix to work with user input, the only way it is working for me is with #define N 5. Other wise I get an error. Also is there an easy way to make a matrix from an input file? The input file would look something like this:
The first number tells the program how many vertices there is, the next ones go like v0 goes to v1 with a weight of 6 and so on. My Kruskal method works I made a partition class to help with the Kruskal algorithm, just can't figure out the matrix really.

4
0 1 6
0 3 4
1 2 2
2 4 9
3 4 7

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
//int X = 5;
#define N 5
Partition p; 

// Finds MST using Kruskal's algorithm 
void kruskalMST(int cost[][N]) 
{ 
    int mincost = 0; // Cost of min MST. 

    // Initialize sets of disjoint sets. 
    //for (int i = 0; i < V; i++) 
    //  parent[i] = i; 

    // Include minimum weight edges one by one 
    int edge_count = 0; 
    while (edge_count < N - 1) { 
        int min = INT_MAX, a = -1, b = -1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { 
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) { 
                if (p.uf_find(i) != p.uf_find(j) 
                      && cost[i][j] < min) { 
                    min = cost[i][j]; 
                    a = i; 
                    b = j; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        p.uf_union(a, b); 
        printf("Edge %d:(%d, %d) cost:%d \n", 
            edge_count++, a, b, min); 
        mincost += min; 
    } 
    printf("\n Minimum cost= %d \n", mincost); 
} 

// driver program to test above function 
int main() 
{ 
  int X;
  /* Let us create the following graph 
       2 3 
    (0)--(1)--(2) 
    |   / \    | 
    6| 8/ \5  |7 
    | /  \ | 
    (3)-------(4) 
    9        */

  ifstream infile;
  string infile_name, outfile_name;
  cout << "Please enter an input file with equations: "; 
  cin >> infile_name;
  infile.open(infile_name.c_str());
  int cost[][N] = { 
    { INT_MAX, 2, INT_MAX, 6, INT_MAX }, 
    { 2, INT_MAX, 3, 8, 5 }, 
    { INT_MAX, 3, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 7 }, 
    { 6, 8, INT_MAX, INT_MAX, 9 }, 
    { INT_MAX, 5, 7, 9, INT_MAX }, 
  }; 

  // Print the solution 
  kruskalMST(cost); 

  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Array sizes have to be constant. If you want to determine the size at runtime you should use `std::vector`.

Comment: I know that would be easier, but we need to use an adjacency matrix. can you do that with vectors?

Comment: Yes. You can have a vector of vectors or a 1D vector wrapped in a class which transforms 2D indices into 1D ones.

Comment: Okay Thank You, I'll try that.